# Set focus on any object

Tags: vba, ms-access

How can someone set the focus of an opened Query object within MS Access using VBA?

I am doing something like this...

```
 If Application.CurrentData.AllQueries(myqueryname).IsLoaded = True Then
      'set the focus

      ' Export to office links for analysis
      CommandBars("Menu Bar").Controls("Tools").Controls("Office Links").Controls("Analyze It With Microsoft Office Excel").accDoDefaultAction
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

again docmd is your friend  :-)

```
'set the focus
DoCmd.SelectObject acQuery, myqueryname, False
```